# Testing Flutter apps with Cypress

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, cypress

Is it possible to test Flutter applications using the Cypress framework instead of using the built-in testing components that Flutter provides? If so, what are the pros & cons of both for Flutter testing if I know Cypress well?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? How did you settle regarding e2e and flutter?

Comment: Nope ... nothing new :)

Comment: cheers! test driver seems to be ok, but far off cypress. Good luck!

Comment: @bionara What does that mean? :)

Comment: This sounds like a great idea, and can probably remove some of the caveats of `flutter drive`

Comment: If you can run your Flutter app also as a web version, you can use Cypress to test it.

Comment: @CanVural that is simply not true. Flutter renders everything as a canvas. Good luck clicking/targeting anything inside a canvas.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, technically, it's possible.

Here's a spec that passes with the basic flutter counter app:

```js
describe('Counter app', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('http://localhost:_example_port_/#/')
      cy.get('flt-semantics-placeholder').click({force: true})
    })
    it('Increments on button press', ()=>{
        cy.get(`[aria-label="0"]`)
        cy.get(`[aria-label="Increment"]`).click()
        cy.get(`[aria-label="1"]`)
    })
})
```

To explain, if you enable semantics by clicking on the hidden 'flt-semantic-placeholder' element, flutter adds a semantics layer used by screen readers. Widgets with tooltips and text are automatically assigned aria-labels, which Cypress can use to find and click on elements. (You can get more control over these labels using a [Semantics Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326902/what-are-the-tags-flt-generated-by-flutter-for-web).)

I found this worked for the canvas renderer, but it crashed when I tried to run multiple test cases in the same run. So, use the html renderer, ie run flutter for the test with something like:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html --web-port 3443
```

Okay, so clicking a button is pretty straightforward. What about other interactions?

**Inputing text into a field:**

Pretty straightforward. See [this example](https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter_cypress/blob/TextInput/cypress/integration/input.spec.js).

**Simulating a scroll event:**

In short, no solution yet. See [this markdown](https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter_cypress/blob/master/scroll.md).

**Simulating drag and drop:**

Not likely. See [this markdown](https://github.com/bendelonlee/flutter_cypress/blob/master/drag.md).

Now for the pros and cons...

Pros:

- Cypress is more user friendly than the integration testing flutter provides. Being able to easily hot reload tests, and being able to click around and inspect a live state of a failing test are nice features.

Cons:

- Can't (yet) simulate scroll or drag.
- Flutter web isn't too performant, and in particular the first load takes a long time. Tests are slow running.
- Nothing indicates either the Flutter team or the Cypress team have any plans to support testing Flutter with Cypress.
- As of this posting, no online guides or articles for testing Flutter with Cypress.

See also:

- [What are the tags, <flt-*> generated by Flutter for Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64326902/what-are-the-tags-flt-generated-by-flutter-for-web)
- https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/07/semantics/

Comment: Is there any way to add test ids on the resulting tags so we can be more specific in our selectors?

Comment: You can control the arial label prop using the semantics widget

Comment: I'd use the semantics, but then I break an useful feature for impaired users.

Comment: To my knowledge there's no way to add a separate test id and aria label is the only way to approximate it. Flutter does not support cypress and visa versa in any official capacity.

Comment: Almost one year since I created a ticket in the Flutter repo asking for testing ids. Please go there and upvote the issue if you really need Cypress testing. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97455