# What are the tags, <flt-*> generated by Flutter for Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I ran Flutter for Web by running `flutter run -d chrome`, then I see bunch of `<flt-*>` tags such as `<flt-glass-pane>`, `<flt-scene>`. I think Flutter Web renders web pages by Canvas and not sure why it generates those html tags. Are they for SEO purposes? Tried to look up documentation but could not find any about it.

I removed `style` attributes from the generates html tags on the default startup page and it looks like below.

```html
<flt-glass-pane>
  <flt-semantics-placeholder role="button" aria-live="true" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enable accessibility"></flt-semantics-placeholder>
  <flt-scene-host aria-hidden="true">
    <flt-scene flt-layer-state="updated">
      <flt-transform flt-layer-state="updated">
        <flt-offset flt-layer-state="updated">
          <flt-picture flt-layer-state="updated"></flt-picture>
          <flt-offset flt-layer-state="updated">
            <flt-clip flt-layer-state="updated" clip-type="physical-shape">
              <flt-clip-interior>
                <flt-picture flt-layer-state="updated">
                  <flt-dom-canvas>
                    <p>You have pushed the button this many times:</p>
                    <p>0</p>
                  </flt-dom-canvas>
                </flt-picture>
                <flt-clip flt-layer-state="updated" clip-type="physical-shape" >
                  <flt-clip-interior >
                    <flt-picture flt-layer-state="updated" >
                      <flt-canvas >
                        <div >
                          <div >
                            <p >Flutter Demo Home Page</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </flt-canvas>
                    </flt-picture>
                  </flt-clip-interior>
                </flt-clip>
                <flt-transform flt-layer-state="updated" >
                  <flt-clip flt-layer-state="updated" clip-type="physical-shape" >
                    <flt-clip-interior >
                      <flt-picture flt-layer-state="updated" >
                        <flt-dom-canvas >
                          <p ></p>
                        </flt-dom-canvas>
                      </flt-picture>
                    </flt-clip-interior>
                  </flt-clip>
                </flt-transform>
              </flt-clip-interior>
            </flt-clip>
          </flt-offset>
        </flt-offset>
        <flt-picture flt-layer-state="updated" >
          <flt-dom-canvas >
            <draw-rect flt-rect="Rect.fromLTRB(-40.0, 28.0, 40.0, 40.0)" flt-paint="SurfacePaintData(color = rgba(0,0,0,0.4980392156862745); maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 4.0); isAntiAlias = true)" ></draw-rect>
            <draw-rect flt-rect="Rect.fromLTRB(-40.0, 28.0, 40.0, 40.0)" flt-paint="SurfacePaintData(color = rgba(183,28,28,0.6274509803921569); isAntiAlias = true)" ></draw-rect>
            <p >DEBUG</p>
          </flt-dom-canvas>
        </flt-picture>
      </flt-transform>
    </flt-scene>
  </flt-scene-host>
</flt-glass-pane>
<flt-ruler-host >
  <div data-ruler="single-line" >
    <p >_</p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="min-intrinsic" >
    <p >_</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="constrained" >
    <p >_</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="single-line" >
    <p >Flutter Demo Home Page</p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="min-intrinsic" >
    <p >Flutter Demo Home Page</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="constrained" >
    <p >Flutter Demo Home Page</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="single-line" >
    <p >You have pushed the button this many times:</p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="min-intrinsic" >
    <p >You have pushed the button this many times:</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="constrained" >
    <p >You have pushed the button this many times:</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="single-line" >
    <p >0</p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="min-intrinsic" >
    <p >0</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="constrained" >
    <p >0</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="single-line" >
    <p ></p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="min-intrinsic" >
    <p ></p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="constrained" >
    <p ></p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="single-line" >
    <p >DEBUG</p>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="min-intrinsic" >
    <p >DEBUG</p>
  </div>
  <div data-ruler="constrained" >
    <p >DEBUG</p>
  </div>
</flt-ruler-host>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flutter has two types of [web renderers](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers).
The code snippet you attached looks like using `html` renderer not the `canvaskit`. So, you are getting DOM elements instead of canvas. When you run `flutter run -d chrome` it builds in auto mode that choose the renderer automatically here it choose html renderer.

The renderer to be used can be enforced by the `--web-renderer` option (`html` or `canvaskit`) in `flutter run` or `flutter build` command.

Now if we look at the DOM elements, some of the DOM elements are common for both renderers.

The pattern looks like the below

```
<flt-glass-pane>
    <flt-semantics-placeholder></flt-semantics-placeholder>
    <flt-scene-host>
        <flt-scene>

           <!-- if canvaskit renderer used here will be one canvas element only 
                and all elements or widgets will be drawn inside 
                the canvas -->

           <!-- if html renderer used here will be DOM elements with 
                different tags and attribute to render the 
                widgets in the browser -->

        </flt-scene>
    </flt-scene-host>
<flt-glass-pane>
```

For html renderer the DOM elements with different tags and attributes inside `flt-scene` are used to render the widgets in browser.

Apart from the container DOM elements (`flt-glass-pane`, `flt-scene-host`, `flt-scene`), the `flt-semantics-placeholder` element is interesting. If javascript `click()` is triggered on the `flt-semantics-placeholder` element it enables accessibility. Technically it creates an overlay of dom elements over the canvas mapped to the widget coordinates, so that the widgets in flutter app can be used by accessibility tools, search engines, and other semantic analysis software to determine the meaning of the application though they are rendered in a canvas as, in canvas we can not know the co-ordinates or read text of the widgets easily (using OCR it is possible but that is different). This is used in flutter driver also [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f789acae4191f585f799be3c4542b16d089224a8/packages/flutter_driver/lib/src/driver/web_driver.dart#L79).

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you so much! It's been a half year since I posted the question but the question in my mind has been blown away :)

Comment: Is there any way to scrap the data from the web with canvaskit renderer?  Is it possible? Seems everything is drawn on canvas.